# Will pubnub work on LAN only?

Tags: javascript, html, lan, pubnub

Anybody here tried pubnub library on LAN only? Like will it work within 10 LAN connected PCs, without internet or external network?

I'm asking this because I need to make a LAN Chat system that's browser based and resources are within a LAN network, no external sources.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, pubnub is a cloud service... AFAIK they do not generally offer their server software for private install within a firewall